# git's pattern matching when both files in the working directory and only in the index match

Tags: git

Observe this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initialize a git repo and make sure to clean old stuff up first.
rm -Rf repo1
mkdir repo1
cd repo1
git init &> /dev/null

# Create an initial commit so we're sure we're not observing behavior
# which only occurs in repos without commits.
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "Initial commit." &> /dev/null

# Get into a new folder to start messing around.
mkdir "some folder"
cd "some folder"

# Introduce and commit a file.
touch file1
git add file1
git commit -m "Add file1." &> /dev/null

# Remove the file just commited and introduce one with a different
# name.
rm file1
touch file2

# `git status` shows that 'file1' got deleted and 'file2' got added.
# Makes perfect sense, thus far.
git status
echo "##################################" # Just to separate outputs.

# Both the added and the deleted file match the pattern 'file*'.
# I therefore expect both the deletion of 'file1' and the introduction
# of 'file2' to be added to the index.
git add file*

# However, `git status` shows us that the deletion of 'file1' is not
# in the index.
git status
echo "##################################" # Just to separate outputs.

# Only if the pattern doesn't match any file existing in the working
# directory, does git add the deletion of 'file1' to the index.
git add *1
git status
echo "##################################" # Just to separate outputs.
```

I don't see how git's behavior makes sense, here. This basically is an as-simple-as-possible lab setup. In a more complicated situation, this got me really confused, today.

Is there any good reason git behaves in this way? I don't mean something like "git behaves in this way if the shell's path name expansion yielded files." but a reason arguing from the user's perspective.

If there is no such reason, stating this provides an answer, too.

Comment: You can't demand an explanation of how a shell script works while avoiding knowledge of how the shell works. If you know how the shell works, it's completely obvious that `git add file*` is the same as `git add file2` when `file2` is the only existing file matching the glob. If you know this, then your question is not a question, it's a rant. If you don't know this, then it's a pretty amazing coincidence that you were able to pick out the correct answer in order to say that's the answer you don't want. Either way, -1 for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that glob expansion (`file*`) is done in the shell, before Git ever even has a chance.

After `rm file1; touch file2`, the shell expands `file*` to `file2` and runs:

```
git add file2
```

which therefore does not add the fact that `file1` is gone.

If you were to *protect* the `*` from the shell, so that *Git* sees it:

```
git add 'file*'
```

*then* Git would do the expansion itself, and add the fact that `file1` is gone.  But this glob star is not protected, so the shell chews on it and spits out `file2`, as the single matching file name.

Just because the shell wants to be confusing, :-) the subsequent `git add *1` matches *nothing*, and instead of replacing `*1` with nothing, the shell leaves it intact.  This passes the `*1` on to Git, just as if you had quoted it.  Git then does its own expansion , and *now* adds the fact that `file1` is gone.

#### Not all shells, not all the time

Not all shells behave this way.  Bash in particular allows you to control the result:

```
bash$ echo 1 *asdf 2
1 *asdf 2
```

This is the standard, default behavior: a failed glob is left as an argument to the command.

```
bash$ shopt -s nullglob
bash$ echo 1 *asdf 2
1 2
```

This is sensible behavior: `*asdf` matches no files, so it expands to nothing.

```
bash$ shopt -u nullglob
bash$ shopt -s failglob
bash$ echo 1 *asdf 2
bash: no match: *asdf
```

This, too, is sensible behavior: `*asdf` matches no files, so it causes the entire command to fail and not to be run at all.

Some other shells have similar controls.  For instance, csh/tcsh defaults to failing (sensible) and allows you to `set nonomatch` to get the default POSIX-shell-style pass-through behavior when there is no match.

#### Shell plus Git equals bad

As a fairly negative side effect of all of this—the fact that Git does its own glob expansion *after* the shell has already done glob expansion—something odd happens if you have a *file* named `*`: protecting the file name from the shell passes the literal character `*` on to Git, which then glob-expands it, even if you did not want Git to expand it.

This sort of thing rarely causes problems because people rarely use the shell glob characters `* [ ?` in file names.  But if someone does use them, some commands get fairly tricky.

In a similar, but less tricky, vein, Git has special treatment for pathspecs that begin with a colon, so that if you have a file named `:x` for instance, you must pass it to Git as `::x` or `./:x`.  We get these syntax-vs-semantics issues whenever some character or sequence has a special meaning: if `!` in a `.gitignore` directive means "don't ignore", for instance, then how do we ignore a file named `!gotcha!`?  Well-written software always has some escape hatch, but designing *good* escape hatches can be difficult.  Git's escape hatch for glob characters, to avoid treating them *as* glob characters, is to prefix the pathspec with `:(literal)`.

Hence, to write the file name `star*fish` and ensure that *neither* the shell *nor* Git tries to do glob expansion, we could use:

```
git foo ':(literal)star*fish'
```

for whatever command `foo` we are using that takes a pathspec (e.g., `git add` or `git rm`).  The quotes protect the `*` from the shell, and then the `:(literal)` protects the `*` from Git.

This all *works*, but I daresay no one would claim that it is beautiful. :-)

Comment: Thank you, especially for including {that,how} bash can be made to stop this weird behavior. Is it not possible for an application to tell bash (using bash in particular as I hardly got experience with any other shell) to not perform path name expansion? I assumed that if it is even possible to tell bash how to do autocompletion, it probably is possible to tell it {how,not} to do path name expansion. I'm even under the impression to have already seen this but am unable to find an example (or it was with a different shell, as they handle file name exp. differently, or I'm just imagining it).

Comment: You can `set -f` or `set -o noglob` (use `set +f` or `set +o noglob` to cancel) to totally disable globbing in bash. But *most* programs expect the shell to do the job for them: this is not a natural way to work on Unix-like systems. Instead of `git add *` it usually makes more sense to do `git add .`, for instance.

Comment: I mean it like this: Can a console program tell the shell (i.e.: Are there any shells which support this?) to not do path name expansion when the user is about to run that program? Similar to how programs can tell the shell to not do autocompletion or even to do autocompletion differently when the user is about to run that program. Not by action of the user and not affecting the behavior of the shell when the user is about to run different programs. Or is this just not something shells offer?

Comment: Since bash is pretty programmable, there might be a way to achieve this (through aliases perhaps). I don't know of anything off hand that does it though.